If permeability is desirable for priming and painting drywall in a basement, why aren't mineral paints more commonly used?
Context: Drywall is up and has two coats of joint compound smoothed and sanded in a basement partition. The wall assembly has a gap behind it 1" off the wall on two sides, and the other sides are exposed to an open utility area. The whole assembly was intended to be fairly breathable to promote drying if/as needed. It's all non-PT wood, rock wool insulation, and green board drywall. The basement has a well-built french drain wrapping around the whole basement with 2 sumps and pumps, one on opposite ends. One dehumidifier set at 45 or 50% RH keeps humidity low for apx 10kWH/day this summer.
Looking to paint, I read that some paints can be food for mold and/or can trap moisture on the wall surface behind them. Seems like more of an issue painting on concrete than drywall. But I also don't like the recommend biocidal paints that resist mold. What makes a lot more sense to me is mineral paints which are naturally not food for mold. These paints are also much more breathable, not reducing the permeability of the wall assembly so far.
My question comes from seeing how inaccessible / uncommon mineral paints are, especially mineral primers. Am I thinking about this wrong and missing something, or why is it not more common to construct walls as a breathable assembly (and keeping it that way by using mineral paints, with the bonus of being inherently mold resistant)?
Just for the environmental/health benefits alone I may go with a mineral primer+paint combo if I can find one. But it seems I'd have to special order, while contractors I'm working with would normally just use a regular drywall primer, and I can paint whatever over that (lime paint or whatever). I could go that easier route - regular primer, 0-VOC paint or mineral paint - but reducing vapor permeability on this new wall by painting it in that way seems like a missed opportunity to get another layer of protection against moisture issues.

Frame challenge: Your "if" is not always true.

@keshlam I get that some wall assemblies try to reduce permeability, but that's not the strategy I'm taking. It seems like promoting drying is a well regarded strategy for basement walls.

Your trepidation about what paint and primer to use is missing the fact that the back of the drywall is not sealed.  So mineral, latex, oil based...it doesn't matter since the back of the drywall is not painted and is still in the same environment.
It is not uncommon to find instances where the finished side of drywall is fine and the backside is hiding mold. The opposite can happen as well.
Mold will grow where the conditions are conducive for it to grow. You have taken steps to reduce those conditions.
If you want to further reduce the probability, the sheen of the paint is more important that the chemical makeup.  A flat or eggshell surface will be more likely to be "friendly" to mold than a semi-gloss or glossy surface.  The obvious tradeoff is the aesthetics. This is a choice that only you can make.

That makes some sense, except about sheen being more important. How could a glossy paint be less conducive to mold than a mineral paint that has no organic contents for mold to grow on? Also, the back of the drywall would get some drying if the outer side of the drywall is more breathable, right? As compared with 'locking in' any moisture that ends up on the back of the drywall (due to ambient humidity rising or some sort of leak), it seems important to let permeability dry out any moisture.

In the real world permeability is not desired, as the common and ordinary sources for  the moisture that mold needs to grow, comes from sources on the outside of the wall.  This is where having the sheen more glossy gives less surfaces for the mold to hold to.   This is why mineral paint is not a common choice, along with the cost being higher and the accompanying consumer rejection of the higher cost V benefit ratio.  However if you desire to spend on the mineral paint , that is your choice...you have free will.

thanks, that answers my question - that in practice, permeability is not as desirable as I'd think it would commonly be, because the idea is to keep moisture from permeating from outside to inside wall assemblies in the first place (thus gloss being better). Understanding that also helps me see when mineral paint is desirable for my uses.
